# dell 1705 wifi adapter

Tags: wireless, dell, adapter

Hello how could i learn the maximum Dbm transmit of my dell 1705 wifi adapter?on b/g/n and bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

Please run the terminal command:

```
iwconfig
```

One of the details listed is Tx-Power. Here is an example from my machine:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"GBR5"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: XX:2B:B0:DC:45:XX   
          Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
```

I am unaware of the method to determine power level for bluetooth.